# Probability of a minimum sum of card values when drawing cards from a custom deck

Tags: probability, summation, card-games

*Apologies if this question has been answered -- I tried searching for an answer but wasn't sure what terminology to use.*

Suppose I have a deck of cards, consisting of $n_1$ ones, $n_2$ twos, etc. (where each $n_x$ can be a different number).

I draw $k$ cards from the deck, and I want to know the probability that they will add up to at least $x$.

I'm looking for a general-purpose formula that I can use for different amounts and values of $n$s, and different values of $k$ and $x$.

Example:

> I have a deck of 7 ones, 4 twos, 13 threes, and 9 fours.  What is the
>   probability of drawing 6 cards and having them add up to at least 13?

I have a basic knowledge of probability, but this problem has a few too many variables for me to work it out.  An explanation of the solution would be most welcome, if anyone is willing and able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost sure the answer to such general question will not be an simple analytical formula, but it can be computed numerically.

First we start with a simple statement: if you choose m objects amongst n, and objects can be of 2 types (e.g. black and white - let there be n_b black objects), than the probability that the number of black objects among the selection $m_b$ is
$$\binom{m}{m_b}\binom{n-m}{n_b - m_b} / \binom{n}{n_b} $$

I have used this formula to implement the algorithm below. The idea is that we iterate over denominations, and for each denomination we condition on how many cards of this denomination (black objects) were selected among whatever number of cards is remaining to select, given total number of cards that remain in the deck and total number of cards of this denomination.

It appears that, for the numbers you give, the answer to your question is **0.674**

The code is below. I have checked it on a few simpler deck compositions, and it seems to give correct result, but please do check it yourself. It is written in Python, your can get it for free and run this code if you need it.

```
def binomialCoefficient(n, m):
    if (n-m) < m:
        return binomialCoefficient(n, n-m)
    result = 1.0
    for i in range(0, m): #0 inclusive, n+1 non inclusive
        result *= (n-i)
    for i in range(2, m+1): #m+1 inclusive, n+1 non inclusive
        result /= (i)
    return result

def probChooseQtyCardsGivenDenomination(qtyCardsDenomination, qtyCardsTotal, 
                                        qtySelectedDenomination, qtySelectedTotal): 
    return (binomialCoefficient(qtySelectedTotal, qtySelectedDenomination) 
           * binomialCoefficient(qtyCardsTotal - qtySelectedTotal, qtyCardsDenomination - qtySelectedDenomination)
           / binomialCoefficient(qtyCardsTotal, qtyCardsDenomination))

# we assume that deckDefinition starts with the biggest denomination
def findDistributionCards(deckDefinition, numberCardsToDraw):

    # initial value if howManyCardsRemain is the cards quantity
    totalNbCards = 0
    for _, cardsQuantity in deckDefinition:
        totalNbCards += cardsQuantity

    # while exploring the tree of possibilities, build an array (per level of tree)
    # which elements are, for each node at this level, 
    # 1. how many cards have already been drawn, 
    # 2. what is the sum of the points of these cards
    # 3. what is the probability to reach this node     
    nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities = [[0, 0, 1.0]]
    for cardDenomination, qtyCardsDenomination in deckDefinition[:-1]: # -1 because we exclude the last element
        new_nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities = []
        for nbDrawnCardsSoFar, sumValues, probability in nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities:
            nbCardsRemainToDraw = numberCardsToDraw - nbDrawnCardsSoFar
            maxNbCanBeDrawn = min(qtyCardsDenomination, nbCardsRemainToDraw)
            for nbDrawnCardsOfThisDenomination in range(0, maxNbCanBeDrawn+1): # up to maxNbCanBeDrawn inclusive
                probToDrawThisNumberOfCards = probChooseQtyCardsGivenDenomination(
                                                    qtyCardsDenomination, totalNbCards, 
                                                    nbDrawnCardsOfThisDenomination, nbCardsRemainToDraw);
                new_nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities.append([
                                                nbDrawnCardsSoFar + nbDrawnCardsOfThisDenomination, 
                                                sumValues + nbDrawnCardsOfThisDenomination * cardDenomination, 
                                                probability*probToDrawThisNumberOfCards]) 
        nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities = new_nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities
        totalNbCards -= qtyCardsDenomination

    # we rely on the fact that numberCardsToDraw < number of cards of the  last denomination
    resultDistribution = []
    last_denomination = deckDefinition[-1][0]
    for nbDrawnCardsSoFar, sumValues, probability in new_nbDrawnCardsSoFar_sumValues_Probabilities:        
        nbOfCardsOfTheLastDenomination = numberCardsToDraw - nbDrawnCardsSoFar
        resultDistribution.append([sumValues + last_denomination * nbOfCardsOfTheLastDenomination, probability])

    return resultDistribution    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    distribution = findDistributionCards(deckDefinition =  [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4]], 
                                         numberCardsToDraw  = 2)
    cumulativeProbability = 0.0
    for sumValues, probability in distribution:
        if sumValues >= 8:
            cumulativeProbability += probability  

    print cumulativeProbability

    distribution = findDistributionCards(deckDefinition = [[1, 7], [2, 74], [3, 13], [4, 9]], 
                                         numberCardsToDraw  = 6)
    cumulativeProbability = 0.0
    for sumValues, probability in distribution:
        if sumValues >= 13:
            cumulativeProbability += probability
    print cumulativeProbability
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  I tried your program with `deckDefinition = [[1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4]]`, `numberCardsToDraw  = 2`, and `sumValues >= 8`.  The two cards can be selected a total of $\binom{16}{2} = 120$ ways, and there a total of $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways that you can get a sum of 8 or more (by choosing two of the four 4s).  Thus the probability in this situation should be $6/120 = 0.05$, but the program reports it as $0.166375$.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the program doesn't allow for two denominations to have the same number of cards.

Comment: I have fixed a bug, and your $0.05$ test passes. Could I have the bounty, pretty please? You can manually override it within 24 hours after it ends.

Comment: I would love to give the bounty, but I already awarded it before you posted your answer.  I don't think there is any way to reverse that now.

Comment: I vaguely remember that there is a card game where each card has a value and the aim is to collect cards so that their total value is as close as possible to the target score, which is 13. Could this be the reason why you ask this question? What is the name of the game?

Comment: I was actually thinking of creating a card game, and wanted to use this to try to balance the values of the cards in the game.

Answer (score 1):

**[Note that this doesn't include number of draws]**

Suppose we have a deck of cards of value $v$(minimum 1 and maximum n) and each cards multiples are $m_v$.
The ways of selection cards so that their sum is $s$ are same as the coeffecient of $x^s$ in:
$$\prod_{v=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m_v}x^{kv}\right)$$
For your case that is equal to the coefficient of $x^{13}$ in:
$$\prod_{v=1}^{4}\left(\large\sum_{k=0,0,0,0}^{7,4,13,9}x^{kv}\right)\\
=(x^8-1)(x^5-1)(x^{14}-1)(x^{10}-1)(x-1)^{-4}$$
That is equal to:
$$\huge30$$

Comment: This is interesting, but doesn't answer the original question.  This is the number of ways there are of getting a sum of 13 (as per the example), while I'm interested in the probability of exactly 6 cards yielding a sum of *at least* 13.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I know I just put it there if it helps in any way, atleast I put up a note at the beginning

Comment: Thanks.  This is one step along the way to the solution.  Hopefully someone else will be able to provide the other steps.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain It involves some logical thinking, I'm being too lazy, maybe I'll add that someother day?

Comment: I think I see one important misstep: $1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8=\dfrac{1-x^{10}}{1-x^2}$ not $\dfrac{1-x^5}{1-x}$. (Analogous issues for the next two factors.)

Comment: @Semiclassical: I'm not sure what you're referring to.  I don't see $\frac{1-x^5}{1-x}$ anywhere in the above formula.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: The function Aditya gives may be expressed as $$\dfrac{1-x^8}{1-x}\dfrac{1-x^5}{1-x}\dfrac{1-x^{14}}{1-x}\dfrac{1-x^{10}}{1-x}.$$ My point is that the first factor is alright, but the others are not: the second should be $$\sum_{k=0}^4 x^{2v}=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8=\frac{1-x^{10}}{1-x^2}.$$ But I've been meaning to put together a long answer which will include that point, so if I'm unclear I'd prefer not to continue in too much depth in comments.

Comment: Well, unfortunately no one was able to give a complete answer, so this answer is getting the bounty for making the best effort.  Thanks, @Aditya!